# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. Error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ticker, tiktok

```js
    import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
    import '../VideoFooter.css';
    import disc from './static/disc.png';
    import MusicNoteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MusicNote';
    import Ticker from 'react-ticker'

    const VideoFooter = () => {
      return (
        <div className='videoFooter'>
          <div className="videoFooter_text">
            <h3>@priyansh21</h3>
            <p>Mindset is key to success</p>
            <div className="video_footer_ticker">
              <MusicNoteIcon className='video_footer_icon'/>
              <Ticker mode='smooth'>
                 {({index}) => (
                   <>
                      <p>This is the Headline of element #!</p>
                   </>
                 )}
              </Ticker>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img className='videoFooter_record' src={disc} alt="" />
        </div>
      )
    }

    export default VideoFooter;
```

I was implementing footer ticker functionality like insta reels and youtube shorts or tiktok and I used this ticker component here which will continuously move from left to right while watching video when I run it, it runs once and then after that error comes in the console that update depth exceed.
Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: This component does not use state or calling setState at all, I suspect the error is from another component. That component should be using setState and maybe `useEffect` or some hooks mentioned in your error descriptions

Comment: but when I remove this ticker component then app runs completly fine